# Why isn't the `background-image` on this <a> tag not visible?

Tags: php, html, css

[**JSFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/6tLzc3xv/2/)

Why isn't my `a.previous-slide-arrow`s' and `a.next-slide-arrow`s' `background-image` visible at all?

I was working on a web page in which I had included this code for the slideshow through the PHP `include` statement. **There, the `vertical-align` applied to `a.previous-slide-arrow` and `a.next-slide-arrow` does not seem to work at all.**

I posted the same code here (*changed the paths to images as the ones I was using there were on localhost, and changed some PHP for loops for writing the `<img>` tag which appears 6 times*) - and **strangely the `vertical-align` does work here, but the `background-image` applied to `a.previous-slide-arrow` and `a.next-slide-arrow` is not visible. Why?**

```css
.image-slideshow-container {} .image-slideshow-container img {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
img.slider-image1 {
  display: block;
}
.first-viewport {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
}
a.previous-slide-arrow,
a.next-slide-arrow {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
  /* =s */
  left: 20px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-left-128.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a.next-slide-arrow {
  right: 20px;
  left: auto;
  background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-right-128.png");
}
.navigation-arrows-container a.previous-slide-arrow:hover,
.navigation-arrows-container a.next-slide-arrow:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.navigation-bullets-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
}
.navigation-bullets-container span {
  display: none;
}
.navigation-bullets-container a {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: #4b4040;
}
.navigation-bullets-container a:hover {
  background: black;
}
.navigation-bullets-container a.active {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-slideshow-container">
  <img class="slider-image1" src="http://i992.photobucket.com/albums/af42/webtreatsetc/Textures%20Patterns%20Brushes%20from%20Webtreats/LightBlur.png" alt="pitcher!" />
  <img class="slider-image2" src="http://m.rgbimg.com/cache1vNdB6/users/x/xy/xymonau/600/ooNRizq.jpg" alt="pitcher!" />
  <img class="slider-image3" src="http://cdn.desktopwallpapers4.me/media/thumbs_400x250/3/23394.jpg" alt="pitcher!" />
  <img class="slider-image4" src="http://papers.co/wallpaper/papers.co-sd19-sand-storm-gradient-blur-8-wallpaper.jpg" alt="pitcher!" />
  <img class="slider-image5" src="http://m.rgbimg.com/cache1sw4YI/users/x/xy/xymonau/600/nxXqi9O.jpg" alt="pitcher!" />
  <img class="slider-image6" src="http://previews.123rf.com/images/hospitalera/hospitalera0805/hospitalera080500016/3089997-Halftone-blue-pattern-with-little-dots-and-some-zoom-blur-applied--Stock-Photo.jpg" alt="pitcher!" />
</div>


<div class="first-viewport">

  <a class="previous-slide-arrow" href="#">&lt;</a>

  <div class="navigation-bullets-container">
    <a class="navigation-bullet1" href="javascript: changeImage(1)">
      <span>Bullet</span>
    </a>
    <a class="navigation-bullet2" href="javascript: changeImage(1)">
      <span>Bullet</span>
    </a>
    <a class="navigation-bullet3" href="javascript: changeImage(1)">
      <span>Bullet</span>
    </a>
    <a class="navigation-bullet4" href="javascript: changeImage(1)">
      <span>Bullet</span>
    </a>
    <a class="navigation-bullet5" href="javascript: changeImage(1)">
      <span>Bullet</span>
    </a>
    <a class="navigation-bullet6" href="javascript: changeImage(1)">
      <span>Bullet</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <a class="next-slide-arrow" href="#">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

---

EDIT: @EternalHour

[image]

Comment: @ris Really? Wow! Your answer is a hotch potch of different properties. Firstly, you change the `color` from `transparent` to `#000`, then you see those ugly `&lt;` and `&gt` signs appearing, so you go ahead and remove those from the mark up. Then you add `z-index: 33333;  background-position: 90px 12px; background-repeat: repeat-x;` for I don't know what reason! You add `!important` to `height` for I don't know what reason. Then you write the answer saying `Check here JSFiddle. You need to ...that CSS`. I added a comment to your answer. That's a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using a background url, in these circumstances you need to specify a `width` and `height` for the container. In this case `a`, otherwise it will not be visible.

```
a.previous-slide-arrow, a.next-slide-arrow {
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. This solves my problem, but I can't help wondering why it works when the URL is of localhost.

Comment: I can't imagine it would work without a width and height. Are you sure that is the only difference?

Comment: I just added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Hmm that is strange, I am going to test that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please use **background** instead of background-image and also give the width and height of the image.

Comment: The width and height works. But this arises another question, what difference does the `background` make as compared to `background-image`?

Comment: It's strange that it works when the image is on the local server. I added a screenshot. Can you tell why?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this `background-size: contain;` to the previous and next arrow classes.

Comment: It's strange that it works when the image is on the local server. I added a screenshot. Can you tell why?

Comment: Isn't related to the instance which serve the client with the image resource.  You have a table, and you use table cells which are dynamically resized and your image is bigger  that result some edge cases.  I recommend you to use an image tag into the anchor tag, if you really need to use an anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Just add "background-size: 100% 50%;"

```
a.previous-slide-arrow,
a.next-slide-arrow {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
  /* =s */
  left: 20px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-left-128.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 50%;   
}
```